# For tensorflow 2.x, how to switch between the CPU and GPU version?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I have updated anaconda to its latest version. It has both tensorflow 2.2 and tensorflow-gpu 2.2 installed. But when I `import tensorflow`, tensorflow-gpu is the default one to be used. Is there a way to switch between them?

The similar questions asked on this website are all for 1.x version. I have tried the solutions and it seems it doesn't work for 2.x version. [Tensor flow toggle between CPU/GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584907/tensor-flow-toggle-between-cpu-gpu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your Problem:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    # YOUR def main() OR model.fit()
```

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # YOUR def main() OR model.fit()
```

This should work with TF2 without sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is :

```
#use gpu 0
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.set_visible_devices(physical_devices[0], 'GPU')

#use cpu
tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')
```